# Forgot login credentials, can I look up my account from my username?

Tags: pokemon-go

My daughter has logged me out of my game and now I can't get back in. She signed me up, but has forgotten how she did it What can I do? I have tried google already and can't find it, it actually loaded my other daughters game. The only thing I remember is my nickname in the actual game.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot look up login information just from a username.  If you have a Google account, check the apps you have authorized in your Google settings.  If you used a Trainer Club login, try resetting your password and using your email address.

If all else fails you may want to open up a ticket with Niantic.

Comment: Thank you for your help and yes have exhausted all options that was why I posted. I did however contact Niantic and am waiting for them to hopefully get me back to playing 

Answer (score 0):

Logging out is risky. I did after playing for a couple of weeks. When I logged back in my account was reset to level 2 with only my first two captures. My nickname had been changed to the first half of my gmail address. (ironically a name I had tried to use during initial sign-up but told was not available)

I opened up a support ticket on the issue and got an automated reply saying to go into my settings and turn off location services for the game and then turn them back on. then uninstall the game and reinstall it, then restart the device. This, the note assured me, would not lose my data since it was all stored on their servers not the device.

Well, apparently it wasn't as I am stuck with the new nickname and loss of all my progress.  And the critical issue response note pointed out that I actually wouldn't hear from them on the problem since the critical support tickets were designed to provide their developers with information to improve the game, not assist individual customers:

> We've received your report and will follow up with you if we need any
> additional information. Please visit our [Known Issues
> page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958208-Known-Issues) to see if your issue is already addressed.
>
> If you're having a temporary issue with Pokémon GO that you're not
> able to reproduce reliably, note that in general, one of the following
> should resolve it:
>
> - Android devices: From your device's Home screen, visit Settings > Touch Apps or Application Manager > Pokémon GO, and touch Force Stop.
>   Visit Storage and touch Clear Cache.
> - iOS devices: From your device’s Home screen, visit Settings > Privacy > Location Services and toggle Pokémon GO off then back on.
> - Remove and then reinstall the Pokémon GO app.
> - Reboot your device.
>
> Your game progress will not be lost by performing these steps, as all
> game progress is stored online.
>
> Please note that you won’t receive a personalized response regarding
> your issue unless more information is needed to investigate. Be
> assured that we review all reports submitted to us and will use your
> report to improve Pokémon GO. Thank you for your help.
>
> -NianticOps