# How can I work out which Google account I used to login with?

Tags: pokemon-go

I updated the game this morning but have forgotten which Google account I associated the Pokemon Go app with.

All I can remember is my game username. Is there anyway to find out which account I signed up with?

I have an iPhone 5c so am on iOS (I don't know if this makes a difference)

Comment: I have an iPhone 5c so am on IOS don't know if this makes a difference?

Comment: this is probably a duplicate http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277034/forgot-login-credentials-can-i-look-up-my-account-from-my-username

Comment: If you have a screenshot from your settings tab it's written on the bottom on the screen... or you still have an activation mail hanging around.

Answer (score 1):

No. This would be an account security threat.

Try every Google account you have.

Answer (score -1):

Check the apps you have authorized in your accounts' Google settings.

If all else fails, open a ticket with Niantic and try to provide proof of owning the username/email.